# Не найден нужный operator<<

Tags: stl, перегрузка-операторов, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool ReadWord(istream& fin, string& str)
{
    str.clear();
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        char c;
        fin.get(c);
        tolower(c);
        if(c>=97 && c<=122)
            str+=c;
        else if (str!=string("")) break;
    }

    if(fin.eof())
        return false;
    return true;
}

void FillMap(istream& fin, map<string,int>& data)
{
    string str;
    while(ReadWord(fin,str))
        ++data[str];
}

struct Pred
{
    int n;
    Pred(int _n=3) : n(_n) {}
    bool operator()(const pair<string,int>& p) { if(p.second>n) return true; return false; }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& fout, const pair<string,int>& p)
{
    return fout<<p.first<<' '<<p.second<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
    ifstream fin("in.txt");
    ofstream fout("out.txt");
    map<string,int> words;
    FillMap(fin,words);
    ostream_iterator<pair<string,int> > file(fout,"\n");
    cout<<"Введите минимальное количество повторений: "<<endl;
    int n; cin>>n;
    Pred condition(n);
    copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(), file, condition);
    system("pause");
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:
Ошибка  1   error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iterator   531

Уже долгое время не могу понять почему. Ведь я то перегрузил его...
А вот так работает:

```
for(map<string,int>::iterator it = words.begin(); it!=words.end(); ++it)
        fout<<*it<<endl;
```

Comment: Как все запутано, но предположу, что возможная причина в том, что вы перегрузили оператор для класса ostream, а сами используете ofstream, производный от ostream:

    template<class _Elem,
 class _Traits>
 class basic_ofstream
  : public basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>

Но это так, предположение, не силен я в STL

Comment: Эээ... А какая строка не компилируется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Видимо проблема заключается в баго-фиче реализации STL от Microsoft. Насколько мне известно код подобный Вашему должен компилироваться)

Суть баго-фичи оказалась в том, что реализация ostream_iterator "не видит" объявлений перегрузок оператора << вне пространства имен std.

Ниже привожу workaround, который решает проблему:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

bool ReadWord(istream& fin, string& str)
{
    str.clear();
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        char c;
        fin.get(c);
        tolower(c);
        if(c>=97 && c<=122)
            str+=c;
        else if (str!=string("")) break;
    }

    if(fin.eof())
        return false;
    return true;
}

void FillMap(istream& fin, map<string,int>& data)
{
    string str;
    while(ReadWord(fin,str))
        ++data[str];
}

struct Pred
{
    int n;
    Pred(int _n=3) : n(_n) {}
    bool operator()(const pair<string,int>& p) { 
        return (p.second > n); 
    }
};

namespace std {
    // объявляем оператор "внутри" пространства имен std
    inline ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const pair<string,int>& p)
    {
        return (out << p.first << ' ' << p.second << endl);
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
    ifstream fin("in.txt");
    ofstream fout("out.txt");
    map<string,int> words;
    FillMap(fin,words);
    ostream_iterator< pair<string,int> > file(fout,"\n");
    cout<<"Введите минимальное количество повторений: "<<endl;
    int n; cin>>n;
    Pred condition(n);
    copy_if(words.cbegin(), words.cend(), file, condition);
    system("pause");
}
```

Сразу оговорюсь, что остальной код я не проверял)

**UPD:** наследование здесь абсолютно не причем)))

Успехов!

Comment: Да, так всё работает! И не знал про такое! Спасибо огромное!) А то в универе как лабы им сдавать - так они первые, а как давать материал на уровне - так сам учи программирование)

Comment: Добавление такой специализации внутрь пространства имен std делает поведение программы неопределенным (см. 17.6.4.2.1 пункт в стандарте).

Comment: zer_ik, если Вам помог ответ пометьте его как правильный)

Comment: gkuznets, я знаю про стандарт и частности п. 17.6.4.2.1 и именно поэтому указал в ответе, что данный подход яавляется workaround) Кроме того в стандарте говорится следующее: 
"A program **may add a template specialization** for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Так что я считаю, что предложенное решение вполне жизнеспособно)

Comment: Я, конечно, ерунду написал, то что вы добавили -- это не специализация шаблона, а просто перегрузка, так это точно UB.